# Spring MVC: Webapp deploys differently using Tomcat rather than Jetty

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, tomcat, jetty

I'm working on a web application using SpringMVC and I'm having difficulty getting my deployments to be consistent with both Jetty and Tomcat.  Currently, Jetty performs the desired behavior, and Tomcat doesn't, so I'm looking for solutions to make them both behave the same.

When I deploy using Jetty, I can navigate to `localhost:8080` and see the index of my web application.

However, when using Tomcat, navigating to `localhost:8080` yields a blank white page, and navigating to `localhost:8080/{the name of my web module}` shows me the index of my application.

I would prefer if both Tomcat and Jetty would load the index of my application when navigating to `localhost:8080`

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Here are the maven plugins I am using:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
        <configuration>
            <stopKey>foo</stopKey>
            <stopPort>9999</stopPort>
            <reload>manual</reload>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <path>/</path>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

I don't know if you guys need to see anything else but just leave a comment and I can include other parts of my code.  Thanks!

Comment: This looks correct.  How are you launching the app - `mvn clean package tomcat7:run` or some other way?

Comment: `mvn jetty:run` and `mvn tomcat:run`

Comment: When using the Tomcat7 Maven plugin, try running the app as `mvn tomcat7:run` or `mvn clean package tomcat7:run`.  The `path` setting in `pom.xml` should work with `tomcat7:run`.  We use the same configuration for multiple apps in development and it runs perfectly fine.

Comment: Also see [sample app](https://github.com/manish-in-java/http-header-splitting) on Github that uses various versions of Jetty and Tomcat and the default context root `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared your servlet-mapping between jetty and tomcat?

This page has a web.xml that may be close to what you are looking for.
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html